# Find the true file names of files in ruby on windows

Tags: ruby, windows

I have a list of files for a Ruby script to process. The script always run on an Windows PC. How can the script find the actual name?

Example:

```
File List -> Actual file on disk 
TEST.TXT  -> test.txt
TeSt.TxT  -> test.txt
```

---

After more testing I found that :

```
puts File.absolute_path("./TEST.RB")
puts Dir["./TEST.RB*"].first
#Path as on disk
puts File.absolute_path("./../Vdd/TEST.RB")
puts Dir["./../Vdd/TEST.RB*"].first
#Path case not as on disk
puts File.absolute_path("./../vdd/TEST.RB")
puts Dir["./../vdd/TEST.RB*"].first
```

Outputs

```
C:/Projects/xcms/software-HEAD/build/tools/Vdd/test.rb
./test.rb
C:/Projects/xcms/software-HEAD/build/tools/Vdd/test.rb
./../Vdd/test.rb
C:/Projects/xcms/software-HEAD/build/tools/vdd/test.rb
./../vdd/test.rb
```

So `realpath` does nothing while `absolute_path` and `Dir["#{file}*"].first` both gets the file name correct but not the path name.

---

So I wrote this function but it corrected some case problems in pathnames but not others.

```
def actual_absolute_path(file)
  file = File.absolute_path(file)
  filename = ''
  file.split('/').each do |s| 
    filename = File.absolute_path(filename + s + "/") + "/"
  end
  filename[0 ..-2]
end
```

It seems a bit random...

Comment: Do you mean something like `filename.downcase` (downcase - is ruby method for string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would expect the method realpath would give you that, but it doesn't
You could use this trick, the real name is all lowercase.

```
file = 'C:/Users/Gebruiker/ruby_werk/files/REAL_NAME1.rb'
p File.realpath file
p Dir["#{file}*"].first
```

gives

```
"C:/Users/Gebruiker/ruby_werk/files/REAL_NAME1.rb" # not correct
"C:/Users/Gebruiker/ruby_werk/files/real_name1.rb" # correct
```

EDIT

Here a version that corercts both path and filename.
Seems that even the OS itself wit a DIR /B /S takes for granted what you provide it and doesn't correct the case. So I convert the path to a shortnamed version and then to longname again.

```
require 'Win32API'

file = 'c:/users/gebruiker/ruby_werk/files/REAL_NAME1.rb'

def longname short_name
  max_path = 1024
  long_name = " " * max_path
  lfn_size = Win32API.new("kernel32", "GetLongPathName", ['P','P','L'],'L').call(short_name, long_name, max_path)
  return long_name[0..lfn_size-1]
end

def shortname long_name
  max_path = 1024
  short_name = " " * max_path
  lfn_size = Win32API.new("kernel32", "GetShortPathName", ['P','P','L'],'L').call(long_name, short_name, max_path)
  return short_name[0..lfn_size-1]
end

def realname file
    longname(shortname file)
end

p realname file
```

gives

```
C:/Users/Gebruiker/ruby_werk/files/real_name1.rb
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets me closer but this does not correct path name.